# Delete CVS folder from all subfolder in windows

Tags: windows, batch-file

I m new to bat file.
I have folder suppose "A" and this folder has subfolder as "B", "C", "D" these folder again has there own subfolders.
my problem is that each subfolders and parent folder have CVS folder , I want to delete that folder from each directories.
How to do that in bat file.

Answer (score 20):

Go to the place where you want to delete all CVS folders. 
In windows in explorer, type "CVS" in the search box. And click enter. 
Select all, and delete. 
Now it is done. :)

Comment: perfect if I could give more than one upvote I would :)

Comment: A little late, but if any of your files contains "CVS", they will get remove too

Answer (score 3):

This should do the job:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('DIR /B /AD /S cvs') DO RMDIR /S /Q %%G
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually you should use `cvs export` to get a clean copy of the course without the working copy folders.

But you can use a `for` loop to remove those folders as well:

```
for /r /d %%f in (*) do if "%%f"=="CSV" rd /s /q "%%f"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to do

```
cvs export -DNOW module_name
```

instead of

```
cvs co module_name
```

Then you don't need to remove anything.