# Removing all CVS related stuff from project

Tags: java, version-control, cvs

I have got a Java project folder which used `CVS`. Now when I imported that project to `eclipse`(on Windows OS), all the unnecessary `cvs` folders are present for each project folder. I want to remove entire CVS related folders because I will use another source code management tool. I manually deleted all the CVS related folders(nearly 50). But when I imported this modified project into different workspace in order to test, all the cvs folders are regenerated. So, my entire work has been wasted. Based on this I think there is one root file which acts as CVS configuration file that is regenerating all CVS folders again.Can someone please help resolve this? I want to completely remove the CVS related stuff from roots. Please go easy if this sounds too noob, but I searched a lot, but I couldn't find solution

Comment: [cvs export](http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/cvs/export-project-from-cvs-repository)

Comment: @HannoBinder I have this project independently. I have just project folder in local directory from where I imported to eclipse. So you mean to say I need to download CVS rep and then put this project into that and then use the export command as mentioned in that blog.

Comment: Actually I was assuming that you still have access to the CVS repositiory where your code is kept. If that repository contains the latest code, you can just `export` from it and get a clean and current project. - Is your project still maintained in the old CVS? If not, then `export` won't help.

Comment: @HannoBinder No, that CVS itself no longer exists. All I have got is this project folder from another person who had taken this code an year ago. So, is there anyway to resolve this? Like importing it to new CVS and then reexporting with that command?

Comment: I see. Maybe this one helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11720844/delete-cvs-folder-from-all-subfolder-in-windows

Comment: However, I don't understand how "all the cvs folders are regenerated" could happen when importing a bare project into a ws.

Comment: Please show us the exact steps which you used to "import this modified project into different workspace"